# Integrating Bloomberg terminal using python Via Excel for Fetching Data

Tags: python, bloomberg

Currently to Fetch Fixed Income Data on the Bloomberg terminal directly I use the SRCH option in the terminal and select Asset Class Governments and corporates. The query that gets executed which I get from Bloomberg is:
`Prefetch the Government and Corporates bonds using JPY,USD and GBR for Maturtiy upto 20 years And the rating Above BBB`
I came across this question [get data from bloomberg api with python via excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54573249/get-data-from-bloomberg-api-with-python-via-excel)
and tried something almost similar however this doesn't work given I'm having a challenge on how to write the query to send to excel.

```
query = """="BSRCH("Asset Classes=Corporate|Goverments","fields = id_isin|maturity|OAS_Spread_bid|")"""
```

Also, I tried the blapi library but nothing in the docs shows the use of SRCH hence i decided to try the excel route.
Anyone with experience on this?

Comment: This is a pretty massive universe! Maybe break it down a little.

Comment: @DS_London to rephrase this, I want to be able to fetch this data programmatically using python.
I know how to do this on the terminal like indicated below. Asset Class, Currency filter, Maturity filter and finally Ratings filter. 
`Prefetch the Government and Corporates bonds using JPY,USD and GBR for Maturtiy upto 20 years And the rating Above BBB` but now I need to convert this to python, how to achieve this query in python is my challenge.

Comment: If you look in the terminal where you define a search, there is a button for copying the BQL query. Hence you can use BQL to return saved searches from the Terminal by name.